# mysql 'ORDER BY' joined columns with NO Values

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I'm joining 3 tables together, one is the `users` holds details of the people involved `events` holds details of the event `invites` holds details of invites that have been sent and the responses of the invitees.

Because I don't have everyone's email address not everyone is invited by email. Everyone who is invited has a row in `invites` the `Response` is recorded as `Y`, `N` or `U` (Yes, No, Unresponded).

The Response column in the joined up table can have 4 results, `Y, U, NUll, N,`

I'd like to sort the table in that ORDER using ORDER BY, but it doesn't work. I'm still fairly new to **mysql** but I'm guessing it's because the `WHERE` clause filter out not relevant results before completing the `JOIN` and the `NULL` value doesn't exist yet.

```
SELECT users.id, name, email, eventdate, response
FROM users 
LEFT JOIN events 
ON users.teamID=events.teamID 
LEFT JOIN invites 
ON events.eventID=invites.eventID
AND users.id=invites.id
WHERE users.teamID=:teamID
ORDER BY 
eventdate DESC,
response='Y' DESC,
response='U' DESC,
response IS NULL DESC,
response='N' DESC



// users
+----+------+-------+--------+
| id | name | email | teamID |
+----+------+-------+--------+
|  1 | SM   | NULL  |      1 |
|  2 | CK   | NULL  |      1 |
|  3 | JG   | NULL  |      1 |
|  4 | DM   | NULL  |      1 |
+----+------+-------+--------+

// events
+---------+--------+------------+
| eventID | teamID | eventdate  |
+---------+--------+------------+
|       1 |      1 | 2017-09-30 |
+---------+--------+------------+

// invites
+---------+----+----------+
| eventID | id | response |
+---------+----+----------+
|       1 |  1 | Y        |
|       1 |  2 | N        |
|       1 |  3 | U        |
+---------+----+----------+
```

What I want to achieve is this?

```
+----+------+-------+------------+----------+
| id | name | email | eventdate  | response |
+----+------+-------+------------+----------+
|  1 | SM   | NULL  | 2017-09-30 | Y        |
|  3 | JG   | NULL  | 2017-09-30 | U        |
|  4 | DM   | NULL  | 2017-09-30 | NULL     |
|  2 | CK   | NULL  | 2017-09-30 | N        |
+----+------+-------+------------+----------+
```

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Can you try    WHERE users.TeamID=:TeamID   ?

Comment: @Strawberry I've added in example tables here.

Comment: @etsa edited, thanks.

Comment: The use of `case` in the answer by @scaisEdge does answer my question, but I'll leave this open in case there are alternate methods to achieve what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be you want use a order by using field

```
  SELECT id, name, email, eventdate, response
  FROM users 
  LEFT JOIN events  ON users.teamID=events.teamID 
  LEFT JOIN invites ON events.eventID=invites.eventID  AND users.id=invites.id
  WHERE TeamID=:TeamID
  ORDER BY eventdate DESC, field( response, 'Y', 'U', 'N') DESC
```

or if you need  a more direct management you can use case when

```
  SELECT id, name, email, eventdate, response
  FROM users 
  LEFT JOIN events  ON users.teamID=events.teamID 
  LEFT JOIN invites ON events.eventID=invites.eventID  AND users.id=invites.id
  WHERE TeamID=:TeamID

  ORDER BY eventdate DESC, case when response =  'Y' then  100 
                                when response =  'U'  then 50
                                when response is null then 20
                                when response =  'N' then 10
                                else 0 end   DESC
```

Comment: I know I can do the `ORDER BY` using `FIELD()` the issue is I want to sort this using a non existent value.

Comment: I'm sorry but how you want order  using an  not existent value .. The value can not be in select but must exist in tables  .. the problem is the is null value ?  anyway answer  updated  with  another suggestion too

Comment: Your use of case allows me to achieve what I want, thanks. But you're missing a bracket before `case`.

Comment: I tested both answers and this method is ever so slightly faster.

Answer (score 0):

Create a field to `order_by` in the result fields

```
SELECT users.id, name, email, eventdate, response, 
   CASE response
     WHEN 'Y' THEN 1
     WHEN 'U' THEN 2
     WHEN 'N' THEN 4
     ELSE 3
   END CASE as order_by
FROM users 
LEFT JOIN events 
ON users.teamID=events.teamID 
LEFT JOIN invites 
ON events.eventID=invites.eventID
AND users.id=invites.id
WHERE users.teamID=:teamID
ORDER BY 
eventdate DESC,
order_by ASC
```

Comment: Thanks, why is `N = 4` or in other words, why did you skip `N = 3`?

Comment: Thanks for this. I tested it there and it doesn't work correctly. I needed to change it to. `   CASE response
     WHEN 'Y' THEN 1
     WHEN 'U' THEN 2
     WHEN 'N' THEN 4
     ELSE 3
   END as order_by`
removing `CASE` after `END` in order to get it to work.